# 8086 assembly: How to copy only few characters from file buffer to a variable

Tags: file, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm having a simple .txt file of which content looks like this:
`aaa bbb ccc (...)`

Each "word" in this file is a kind of separate instruction.
I'd like to read these words one after one, writing each word to a dw "temp" variable (ex. temp dw 'aaa') to use it first, and then read another word and use it in similar way.

I am using DOSBox, TASM and intel 8086 assembly. I've already tried to figure it out by myself, looking through these forums as well, but found no solution I could understand or use.

I've got a function "readFile" ready, file is being opened, it is valid and it is already being seen by program, so that works.

```
    readFile:
    mov ah,3Fh          
    mov cx,3     ; to read 3 bytes (letters) at single run
    mov dx,offset buffer
    mov bx,handler     ; handle for file
    int 21h 

    cmp ax,0
    je endOfFile

    mov ax,[buffer] <---
    mov [temp],ax   <--- these lines obviously won't work

    CALL execute

    jmp readFile

...

handler dw 0
buffer dw 255 DUP(0)
temp dw ?  <--- this should be 'aaa', then 'bbb', then 'ccc' and so on
```

Now the question is, how can I "catch" only first word 'aaa' from file to a temp variable, then use it the way I want, go through space and then "catch" the second word 'bbb' to temp (and so on)?

Current code just doesn't work, like if the buffer was not being saved properly, although it compiled.

I've got a feeling that I'm missing something basic here, but I can't figure that out. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: alternatively, I thought can abandon using this "temp" variable, and use that 'aaa' directly in code somehow, but I don't know how. I forgot to mention, that 'aaa' in file corresponds to a name of constant which I need to currently load, ex. aaa equ 0111.

All the problem is, I just want to use the word from a file (let's say this aaa word), and put it directly to use in the code, like

`mov    ax,aaa` <-- this would be constant named "aaa" loaded to ax, and the name of this constant to load is this 'aaa' word from file.

I hope it is quite clear what is the purpose of these separate words from file.

Comment: `dw 'aaa'` uses 4 bytes, two words, including padding at the end of the 3-byte string to make it a whole number of words.  An x86 "word" is only 2 bytes, so `'aaa'` doesn't fit in one.

Comment: I've edited the post. I can abandon the idea with the "temp" variable totally, but then I'd need to catch the single word anyway - because this word is a name of constant in program, which I need to load. So if I read 'aaa' in file, I'd load the constant named 'aaa' in my code (ex. mov ax,<aaa>, where <aaa> would be directly the word I read from file).

Comment: You mean you have a symbol + data like `aaa: dw 123` somewhere in your program, and you want to translate strings into 16-bit numbers using those labels?  Symbol/label names aren't available at runtime, you'll have to implement a hash table or other map data structure.

Comment: I've got a set of constants (aaa equ 1000; bbb equ 2000 etc.) and the .txt file is only supposed to "tell" which constants and in which order to use in the main program at a time. Similar to playing music via assembler, where in separate file you just tell the notes and durations to use. Isn't there really any easier solution than implementing whole structures to do that? If so, then I will look for that, yet I hope there is another way as for the beginner...

Comment: `equ` constants are available at assemble-time only.  There's nothing like `eval` in perl or other high level languages that let you treat runtime data as code with access to symbol names.  If you want to map 3-character string to numeric constants, you need to do it yourself.  The simplest way might be a chain of cmp/jne that falls through until you find a match, checking just the first 2 bytes of what you read into an input buffer.  like `cmp word [buf], 'aa' / `jne no_aa` / `mov ax, aaa`.  You could add an extra check for the 3rd byte if you want to reject "aab".